# Google Analytics Event tracking setup

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

Can someone help me write the proper GA setup for the following HTML code?
I"m trying to track the downloads of the media kit and the capabilities (both PDF's)
I'm running analytics.js and it's pretty connfusing to me unfortunately.

Here is the code.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
        <div class="tabs-content-container">
            <div class="eight columns">
                <img src="img/brochure.jpg" alt="blog" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
            </div>
            <div class="four columns">
                <h3>Download Company Overview</h3>
                <p>Thank you for taking the time to learn more about our company. The additional information in these brochures will tell you more about our history, products and references.</p>
                <p>Our printable company overview brochure is now available for download. Both documents require <a target="_blank" href="http://get.adobe.com/reader/"> Adobe Reader</a>. Click the links below to download our company’s Capabilities and Media Kit.</p>
                <a target="_blank" href="Capabilities.pdf">Download Capabilities &nbsp;&#8594;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
<!-- end section-tabs -->

<section class="msg-container diff-msg" style="margin-bottom:0;">
    <div class="msg-inner-container">
        <a target="_blank" href="MediaKit.pdf" class="download">Download Media Kit</a> 
    </div>
</section>
```

the issue is that I'm used to the ga.js style of event tracking in which I would have done something like this: `<a href="MediaKit.pdf" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'download', 'one-sheeter', 'about harbordev',, false]);" class="download">Download Media Kit</a>`. That however doesn't work with analytics.js and the documentation doesn't really make sense to me.

Thank you

Comment: ...and here's the documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/

Comment: What's the issue you are having? and what attempt have you made towards a solution?

Comment: the issue is that I'm used to the ga.js style of event tracking in which I would have done something like this: <a href="MediaKit.pdf" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'download', 'one-sheeter', 'about harbordev',, false]);" class="download">Download Media Kit</a>. That however doesn't work with analytics.js and the documentation doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it? Make sure that you have `target="_blank"` (or at least open the link with JavaScript) so that way you can be sure that your request to track the event is completed before the user navigates away from the current page (and on to `MediaKit.pdf`)

Comment: for analytics.js the tracking code needs to be written differently. It now looks like this: ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', {'page': '/my-new-page'});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
onClick="ga('send', {'hitType': 'event', 'eventCategory': 'download', 'eventAction': clickedDownload', eventLabel': 'Capabilities' });"
```

thanks to everyone who tried to help.